# C# Regex Match between with or without new lines

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match text between two delimiters, `[% %]`, and I want to get everything whether the string contains new lines or not.

**Code**

```
string strEmailContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
string commentPatt = @"\[%((\r\n?|\n).*(\r\n?|\n))%\]";
Regex commentRgx = new Regex(commentPatt, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**Sample Inputs**

```
//Successful
[%
  New Comment
%] other content from input

//Match: [%\r\nNew Comment\r\n%]

//Fail
[% New Comment %]

//Match: false

//Successfully match single line with
string commentPatt = @"\[%(.*)%\]";

//Match: [% New Comment %]
```

I do not know how to combine these two patterns to match both cases. Can anyone provide any assistance?

Comment: Since `.` matches any character except `\n`, try `string commentPatt = @"\[%(.|\n)*%\]";`.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to match any whitespace instead of just newline characters? If so, you can use the shorthand whitespace character class `\s+` in the place of `\r\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text between two delimiters you need to use *lazy matching* with `.*?`, but to also match newline symbols, you need `(?s)` singleline modifier so that the dot could also match newline symbols:

```
(?s)\[%(.*?)%]
```

Note that `(?s)\[%(.*?)%]` will match even if the `%` is inside `[%...%]`.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)%5C%5B%25(.*%3F)%25%5D&i=%2F%2FSuccessful%0D%0A%5B%25%0D%0A%20%20New%20Comment%0D%0A%25%5D%20other%20content%20from%20input%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FMatch%3A%20%5B%25%5Cr%5CnNew%20Comment%5Cr%5Cn%25%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FFail%0D%0A%5B%25%20New%20Comment%20%25%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FMatch%3A%20false%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FSuccessfully%20match%20single%20line%20with%0D%0Astring%20commentPatt%20%3D%20%40%22%5C%5B%25(.*)%25%5C%5D%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FMatch%3A%20%5B%25%20New%20Comment%20%25%5D). Note that the `]` does not have to be escaped since it is situated in an unambiguous position and can only be interpreted as a literal `]`.

In C#, you can use

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?s)\[%(.*?)%]");
var res = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the new lines in C#.. I'm not sure why

Comment: It does as there is no trimming. Show me your code. See [my demo](http://ideone.com/o8OwEs).

Comment: Yes I saw that. That's why I am marking this as answer. Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: I added that note to the answer. Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
\[%([^%]*)%\]
```

It captures all characters between "`[%`" and "`%]`" that is not a "`%`" character.

Tested @ [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cR7oO3/2)

If you want to "see" the "`\r\n`" in your results, you'll have to escape them with a `String.Replace()`.

See [Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wK0vhJ)

Comment: This works great! only thing is it does not capture the new lines. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat What do you mean it doesn't capture the new lines?  Look at the Regex101 link.  The first match has the newlines captured.

Comment: It 'matches' but they are parsed out in the match? Does that make sense? I do not see any '\r\n` in the matched text

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat I think I understand what you're wanting.  See updated answer.

Comment: Interesting.. you're pattern works in Fiddle without the replace exactly how I want it too but running it thru the C# Regex does not seem to keep the new lines.. let me check again